# When do we need a spring configuration in a multi module maven project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have set up my project in multiple modules based on the Spring framework. Currently there is only one runnable application combining all those modules.

Some of the modules provide functionality that might be reusable by other projects (or at least I could imagine reusing them in an other project). Some (but not all) modules also provide s spring `Configuration`. However when trying to create an application based on that configuration alone, requires defining many beans on top. This suggests that the configuration at that level does not make much sense, as there are dependencies on the level of `Maven`, which are not reflected in the Spring configuration.

As I am moving toward `Spring Boot` does this set up make sense or should the beans be defined at the level, where the configuration dependencies and Maven dependencies do match?